# How to figure out xpath for IMPORTXML in Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

Thank you guys in advance for your attention

I'm trying to use the IMPORTXML function on Google Sheets.

For example:=IMPORTXML("https://www.linkedin.com/in/salesmanagerdigital/, XMLPATH) should return "Senior Enterprise Account Executive, Southern Europe", which is the complete Role.

Firefox Full xPath Finder extension gives me:

/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/main/section[6]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span/span[1]

When I try this in Google Sheets it returns an error: #N/A (Import Content is Empty).

Thanks you so much for your support.

Comment: Filling google sheets is not programming (?)

Comment: Unfortunately it appears LinkedIn does not allow for web scraping.